# OpenMP matrix multiplication gives inconsistent results

Tags: c++, openmp

When performing a matrix/vector multiplication, I get two different values when running the code in parallel using OpenMP, or when running it in a single thread. If I export the environment variable

```
$ export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1
```

the multiplication gives an identical results, but if I set the value to 2 or higher, the multiplication is sometimes consistent, and sometimes not.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <omp.h>

double* parMatVecMul(double* A, double* v, int M, int N){
    double* C = new double[M];
    double dot;
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i<M; i++)
    {
        dot = 0;
        for (int j=0; j<N; j++)
            dot += *((A+i*N) + j) * v[j];
        C[i] = dot;
    }
    return C;
}

double* matVecMul(double* A, double* v, int M, int N){
    double* C = new double[M];
    double dot;
    for (int i = 0; i<M; i++)
    {
        dot = 0;
        for (int j=0; j<N; j++)
            dot += *((A+i*N) + j) * v[j];
        C[i] = dot;
    }
    return C;
}

int main(){
    int size = 40;
    double* mat = new double[size*size];    
    double* x_true = new double[size];
    double* b = new double[size];
    double* bx = new double[size];

    for( int iter = 0; iter < 10; iter++){  //Run code 10 times to find error

        for( int i =0; i < size; i++)       //Initialize symmetric matrix
            for( int j =0; j < size; j++){
                mat[i*size + j] = rand() / double(RAND_MAX) + 0.2;
                mat[j*size + i] = mat[i*size + j];
            }
        for( int i =0; i < size; i++){      //Make matrix diagonally dominant
            mat[i*size + i] += size;
            x_true[i] = rand() % 10 + 0.2;
        }

        double error = 0;;
        b = matVecMul(mat, x_true, size, size);
        bx = parMatVecMul(mat, x_true, size, size);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            error += fabs(b[i] - bx[i]);
        printf("b error: %f\n", error);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
$ ./a.out 
b error: 0.000000
b error: 0.000000
b error: 0.000000
b error: 0.000000
b error: 0.000000
b error: 0.000000
b error: 0.000000
b error: 34.747142
b error: 0.000000
b error: 0.000000
```

Why are the parallel operations sometimes incorrect?

Comment: Give dot local scope instead of shared.

Comment: In the parallelised function there is a race on `dot` -- multiple threads update it without coordination.  As a general rule if a parallel program works on one thread but not (reliably) on multiple threads think *data race*.  @tim18's already told you how to solve the problem.